# Don’t migrate cross-posts

Tags: discussion, migration

I flagged [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21576/highlighting-color-nstableview-cocoa) as being off-topic, and later I noticed that the same question had been [cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038060/highlighting-color-nstableview-cocoa). I then added a comment to the Ask Different question stating it was a cross-post:

[image]

Even with this comment, the question ended up being migrated to Stack Overflow, resulting in a duplicate there:

- Original cross-post on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038060/highlighting-color-nstableview-cocoa
- Migrated question from Ask Different, resulting in a duplicate question on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038709/change-highlighting-color-in-nstableview-in-cocoa

Is there some other workflow that’d make it more obvious to Ask Different moderators that a question is a cross-post and shouldn’t be migrated at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it was a matter of crossed signals. I loaded the page before you posted your comment, you posted the comment, and then I migrated it (8 seconds later) without knowing about the duplicate. And unfortunately, there's no way to un-migrate from this end - it has to be dealt with on Stack Overflow.

If I see that there's a cross-post on another site I won't migrate. The issue here was that I didn't see it and it clearly was a programming question, so I just moved it over.

Comment: Or, simply don't cross-post and let the community and mods sort it out.

Comment: Did you flag the SO question?  Popping into the Teacher's Lounge is also a quick way to get stuff like this handled.

Comment: Hah, eight seconds!

Comment: @Bavarious Actually I did the math wrong, it was 12 seconds.